# How to call GTalk to GTalk from Android?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, google-talk

I need it badly. I know Google voice is there, but it's not available in India.

**Clarifications**
Need any good client application (Google Talk / Jabber client) that supports voice calls to and from GTalk users.

Thanks [@Matthew](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/1465/matthew-read)

Comment: Does it have to be gtalk to gtalk, or will any voice chat app do?

Comment: I've skype too. I use it for office purpose. But my friends remain online on GTalk so doesn't make sense using anything else.

Comment: Have you tried through the web browser?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do voice chat through gtalk on Android

Comment: To clarify: He needs a Google Talk / Jabber client that supports voice calls, he does not need some way to use the official Talk app to do voice calls.

Comment: Will try @Matthew and let you know

Comment: Hi @Matthew! I tried opening Gmail in browser. It opens mobile version first. At the bottom I selected HTML Basic (no standard view option available). On HTML Basic view at the bottom of page, I selected Standard view and it took me back to Mobile version of GMAIL. So in short it doesn't work in android browser on Froyo.

Comment: @Ismail You can try setting your user agent to Desktop to trick the website: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6233/how-can-i-change-the-user-agent-for-the-stock-browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fring or Nimbuzz apps from the market place both allow you to do voice calls using gTalk.

Comment: Does it work with Froyo?

Comment: The descriptions of the apps say they work for all android versions so should be ok.

Comment: @Ismail They work with Froyo in general but sometimes they may not work on specific devices.  Try them :)

Comment: They both worked on my HTC Magic so I imagine there shouldn't be any problems on the more modern devices.

Comment: Nimbuzz works on my device. :)

Answer (score 4):

Google Talk Video/Voice support will be rolled out shortly on all Android 2.3 Gingerbread devices or on the Nexus S now (but as an OS update, not an app update, so you would find it in Settings, not in Market)

Comment: See this for more info from the official Google Mobile Blog http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2011/04/video-chat-on-your-android-phone.html

Comment: When you say all android 2.3 devices. Do you really mean all or do you mean at the discretion of the manufacturer and cellular provider. Because if so a lot of android 2.3 devices wont ever get it.

Comment: It might be at carrier discretion but you would get this faster than you would get 2.3 if you now had 2.2 (like me :( )

Answer (score 2):

Use **Fring**. It can connect to gtalk and enable you to talk to your gtalk buddies. But it mutes in Samsung galaxy 3.

Comment: can it connect to gtalk with voice?

Comment: @nathan What do you mean by that?

Comment: the gtalk client on android can only do text chat, while the talk client in the gmail website can also do voice.  Does Fring have the same limitation as the native android gtalk client, or can it also do voice like the gmail version?

Comment: Of course it can do voice. That is what the OP wanted to do. That is also what I meant when I said "[Fring]..enable you to **talk** to your gtalk buddies"

Answer (score 2):

You can do video chat through Google Talk on Honeycomb (Android 3.0), which is only available on the [Motorola Xoom](http://motorola.com/xoom) at this point in time. No word on when this feature will trickle down into newer versions of Android (2.4+) or if this will become a standalone/updatable market app like Gmail, YouTube, etc.