# Spoof user-agent in Firefox 4 for android

Tags: 2.2-froyo, firefox-for-android, user-agent-string

*Question*: Is there a way to spoof your user-agent header in Firefox for Android?

*Explanation*: The thing that's kept me using Dolphin for Android for the longest time is the fact that it can spoof your user-agent header to quickly and easily avoid the mobile atrocities some people develop for their sites, still giving me the option to navigate there manually if I prefer it. I don't see this option for the latest release of Firefox for Android.

It seems to load much faster and I prefer the interface to all other browsers I've tried on Android, but that feature is the only thing making me keep dolphin on my phone. Am I missing it, is there an extension that allows it, maybe an option in the phone system, or is this just not in the cards for FF on Android? If not, I'll redirect this to the Mozilla devs as a feature request, but I figured I'd come here first to see if I'm just missing an option to do it.

Comment: To save space, you could just use Firefox+Stock instead of Firefox+Stock+Dolphin.  To change the user agent for the stock browser: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6233/how-can-i-change-the-user-agent-for-the-stock-browser

Comment: I'd forgotten to check back with the stock browser in awhile, I think I'll do that. Thanks for the heads up Matthew!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is indeed an extension which does this. It's called [Phony](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/addon/phony/) and you should be able to find it if you use the addons search from within Firefox Mobile. After it's installed, you'll get a new drop-down entry in your preferences menu where you can choose your user agent (the most recent version actually has more choices than the picture below):

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! I kept searching for it but could never find the right search terms.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Firefox (and Chrome) now have a ["Request desktop site"](https://www.techbout.com/request-desktop-version-website-android-phone-17720/) setting in their menus.

[image: Firefox menu desktop site version selection]