# How to force load desktop version of website?

Tags: browser

Mobile optimised websites are nice but it happens too often that they omit some crucial functionality.

Is there a way how to cheat the browser detection or force-load the desktop version of any website?

Comment: Closely related: [How can I change the user agent for the stock browser?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/6233/1465)

Answer (score 6):

- Open the web browser
- navigate to `about:debug` (make sure you press the "go" button, not search)
- nothing will seem to happen, but it did...
- press the menu key and select "More"
- Now select Settings.
- Scroll down and you should see an option for "UAString" or "Change User Agent".

Comment: I think that option appears normally,without the about:debug trick. It does on both my phone and honeycomb tablet?

Comment: @Oatman It depends on which device you have, see [How can I change the user agent for the stock browser?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/6233/1465)

Comment: This setting change doesn't seem to stick. If the application closes completely, it reverts back on the next load. Any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

[Dolphin Browser Mini](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dolphin.browser&feature=search_result) has a setting in the tools menu that is an easy way to switch between user-agents. It includes viewers for:

- Android (default)
- Desktop
- iPhone
- iPad

plus, it works much faster than the stock browser!

Answer (score 1):

The recent version of Opera Mobile (11.1) also includes the User Agent option (mobile / desktop) 
see: Settings/Advanced/User Agent

Answer (score 1):

Type `about:useragent` in the address bar then simply choose `Desktop.`  Couldn't be easier!

Note that this doesn't work for all devices, see [How can I change the user agent for the stock browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/6233/1465)

Answer (score 0):

You can select the user-agent on both android tablets and android phones, it's in the settings menu :-)

Comment: Where? I can't find it on my Galaxy S2 / Android 2.33

Comment: you cant find it, see my post, it should make it "visible"