# How to browse American Express in desktop mode on Android?

Tags: browser

It's seemingly impossible to browse American Express `www.americanexpress.com` in desktop mode on Android.

I've tried Chrome and Dolphin browser, also tried searching for a button on the site that would bring desktop mode.

Comment: Related: [How to force load desktop version of website?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/10959)

Answer (score 2):

1. Install [Firefox browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) by Mozilla.
2. Visit [American Express](https://www.americanexpress.com/)
3. Click the three vertical dots near address bar and select "Request Desktop site".

   [image: IMG: American Express Desktop mode in Firefox 40]

   <sub>Screenshot - (Click to enlarge image)</sub>

You may also try to use their Android app "[Amex Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.americanexpress.android.acctsvcs.us)" available on Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

- Visit [americanexpress.com](http://www.americanexpress.com) in your default browser.
- Scroll down to the end of the page and Select "Full Site"
- Disable JavaScript in Site settings

  [image: Screenshot]
   <sub>Click on image to enlarge</sub>
- I'm using [Chrome Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) as my default browser and it works.

Comment: The [Mobile | Full Site] link is not visible to me in Chrome. Can you post the URL of the screenshot you posted? Yours is different than mine. Also what version of chrome are you using?

Comment: I agree with Lucky. I don't see that option either. I even tried `global.americanexpress.com` but to no avail.

Comment: You're right, my bad, the url in my browser got redirected to  "americanexpress.co.in". Chrome's _request desktop site_ does not work with "americanexpress.com"

Comment: @Lucky url `www.americanexpress.com` ignores the _request desktop site_ from chrome when javascript is enabled. So disabling the javascript did the trick. @Firelord Edited the post, now everything works like a charm.