# Hiding device name from website

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-messenger

Is there any way to hide my device name from website e.g. whenever I login Facebook it is able to determine the type of browser 'chrome on Android' and also device name. Is there any way to hide this information or send incorrect information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## About user-agent

If you're referring to hiding your [user-agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent), this can easily be done. Your user-agent is a short piece of text your browser automatically transmits to the server when you request for a web page. This helps the server identify the browser and operating system you're running and possibly serve up the most appropriate page (e.g. a mobile-friendly version).

On a Nexus 7, the user-agent looks something like this:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; Nexus 7 Build/JRO03D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Safari/535.19

This indicates the Nexus 7 is running Android 4.1.1 and Google Chrome version 18.0.

## Changing your user-agent

To change it on the Samsung Galaxy Touchwiz stock browser, take a look at [How can I change the user agent for the stock browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6233/how-can-i-change-the-user-agent-for-the-stock-browser).

There are several alternative browsers that allow you to easily change your user-agent, including the well-known [Dolphin Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser). If you're paranoid about privacy, the [Dolphin Zero](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dolphin.browser.zero) browser might interest you as well.

If you're using Google Chrome, there appears to be [no official way](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/wz20WE2NGg8) to do this right now, but by checking the *Request Desktop Site* checkbox, you can change your user-agent to a Desktop one that hides the fact you're browsing from an Android device.

That being said, **this is far from foolproof**. Your screen width and height will easily give away the fact you're browsing from a mobile device (and possibly even a non-iOS device).